# Force browser to load the content again when open a new tab

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I use window.addEventListener('load'... to check whether the content is loaded.

This look correct when I open a window with the first tab. However, when I open another new tab, the event is not triggered because the browser doesn't load the content anymore.

Is there any way to force the browser to load again?

Comment: what do you exactly mean by "loading" the content ? Do you mean to reset the web page and download all the content from the server again (if in your server there is a cache definition you may need to start from there instead of finding solution in the client side)

Comment: Also : any example of your code implementation could be usefull in order to help you

Comment: Here is my code 

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
      this.x();
    });

When I open a new tab, look like this.x() is not fired

Comment: I understand that, but you tagged your question with "reactjs" tag. Now : if you implement this code in a componenet within a lifecycle method and not in the proper way, then this could be your issue....so the question is : where do you put this code and How did you implement it (inside which method of your component)

Comment: ComponentDidUpdate

Comment: can you please try to put it in the componentdidmount ? Let us know if it resolves your problem